# Don't show dropdown choices with angular-ui-select before entering data?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I am using the angular-ui-select directive to create an auto-complete input field.  I want to be able to click and focus the field without the dropdown options appearing.  The Plunker example in the documentation works this way, but I cannot get mine to behave correctly.  Please help.

Here is my code:

```
<ui-select ng-model="customer.selected" theme="bootstrap">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Start typing..">{{ $select.selected.family_name }}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="customer in customers | filter: $select.search">
        <div ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml((customer.family_name | highlight: $select.search))"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Here is their Plunker example that is working the way I would like it to.

http://plnkr.co/edit/a3KlK8dKH3wwiiksDSn2?p=preview

Comment: Hi! Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I have a same issue. I want to be able to click and focus the field without the dropdown options appearing.

Here I am sharing my solution. May be it will help someone. I made changes in `Selectize theme` example in plunker shared by `@Corey Quillen`. I had cleaned up other things so it will help.

1) Here first I had add `reset-search-input="false"` in `ui-select` directive. So it will not reset search input.

2) Then I had replaced `filter` with custom filter `propsFilter`. Which is already useing in `Select2 theme`. And put

`if(!props.name.length){
     return out;
 }`

in filter above `If condition`. In demo.js file.

So data return empty if no search text entered.

Here is the plunker [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/37EaAerec72L0yXm2oUA?p=preview) of that.

Answer (score 0):

ui-select by default shows a dropdown, I dont think we can change that. But you can change its binding data. In the plunker example the ui-select is bind to model 'address.selected', which initially is empty, thus nothing pops up. But once you start typing the refresh will call the function refreshAddress() to populate the results into address. Once the results are populated, ui-select finds that its model(address) has data and start showing a dropdown. After you have searched for something, try to click on the textbox, it will still show you the result, beacuse they are still present in the model.

Since, you are trying it with a local variable I suppose, it is pre-populated with data for ui-select and hence it shows it. I think you should try to make a request in you code to get that data and use refresh and refresh-delay. If you dont have a web service and want to use local data, I would suggest bind the select to an empty model and put data into that using a custom function for refresh, you might have to write a custom search functionality into the refresh function, but you can use javascript's search() or indexOf() for that.